# Connecting Crystal Reports to an SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

So I've gone into the 'database expert', but I can't seem to figure out how to add the db to the report.

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm using CR 13 and SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We are using CR 11 R2 ... and I am not sure if option is changed or not for CR 2013..

But in CR 11 R2,this can be done by going in Database Expert, select `Create New Connection`. In that look for `OLE DB (ADO)` data source. Once you open up the OLD DB provider you should see `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server`