# How to use service account for crystal report to connect to sql server datasouce?

Tags: crystal-reports, sql-server-2016

we use the service account to log in SQL Server (i.e domain\accountName, account password or window authentication). There's a service account dedicated for running a report. I need to change the data source for crystal report to use the service account (or using impersonation) but seem like CR can't connect to SQL Server using service or AD account. I've tried several DB connection settings but none of them were able to connect to SQL SERVER with a service account.

[image: OLE DB Connection settings]

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to connect from CR, and can you connect with any other application using the service account?

Comment: which version of CR used , just check this step - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189382/connecting-crystal-reports-to-an-sql-server

Comment: I'm using CR13. I'm able to connect to sql server with .net web app (MVC, webform) using the same service account.

Comment: This thread looks quite stale, but I'm also having a similar problem. Will check the shared link to see if there's a resolution there...

Just checked. That's not the solution to the problem.